# Elasticsearch: multi indices one type OR one index multi types

Tags: elasticsearch

As [The Definitive Guide -> Indexing Employee Documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_indexing_employee_documents.html) said

> Relational DB  ⇒ Databases ⇒ Tables ⇒ Rows      ⇒ Columns
>
> Elasticsearch  ⇒ Indices   ⇒ Types  ⇒ Documents ⇒ Fields

And [The Definitive Guide -> Index Aliases and Zero Downtime](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html) said

> Be prepared: use aliases instead of indices in your application. Then you will be able to reindex whenever you need to. Aliases are cheap and should be used liberally.

The question is, if `Indices` just like `Databases`, then if I want to rebuild one `Type`(`Table`) I have to reindex the whole `Database`, is that reasonable ? (this is `one index multi types`).

Or I have to create many indices for a project and every index has just one type, that sounds like a project has dozens databases!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your confusion. Say You have one index named *my_index* and three types *type1*, *type2* and *type3*. You create an `alias` *alias1* for this index.

Now you want to change mapping of *type1*, so you need to reindex every document of *type1* but you want to do this with **zero downtime** so you create a new index *index2* and reindex documents of *type1* and now if you want *alias1* to refer to new index, problem will arise and as you said you will have to reindex all other types too only if you want `zero downtime`. If you are ok with downtime then obviously you can delete all the documents and reindex them.

To solve the above issue you should create `multiple aliases` for the same index beforehand as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime),look for the section named *Using aliases for greater flexibility* . You create 3 `aliases` for current index like this

```
curl - XPOST localhost:9200/_aliases - d ' {
    "actions": [{
        "add": {
            "alias": "type1_alias",
            "index": "index1"
        }
    }, {
        "add": {
            "alias": "type2_alias",
            "index": "index1"
        }
    },
    {
        "add": {
            "alias": "type3_alias",
            "index": "index1"
        }
    }]
}
'
```

Now you index *type1* docs to *type1_alias* and so on. Now whenever you want to rebuild any specific type you can create new index and assign specific type alias to that new index. You also have to remove that particular type documents from old index(*index1* in this case)

This would have been lot easier if `alias` had support on type level, somebody opened an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11905) about that but it was closed due to complexity I guess.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

You can work with one index and multiple types.

You can re-index documents of a given type within an index without affecting other documents in the same index but belonging to other types. As a matter of fact each document in an index can be re-indexed without having to re-index other documents.